# App thinks what is installed on iPhone 3 or 4, but my iPhone is 5

Tags: ios, iphone

On iOS 7, my application thinks it is installed on iPhone 3 or 4, but i'm on an iPhone 5.
Main View and other Views is smallest: 3,5 inch.

```
NSLog(@"bounds %@", NSStringFromCGRect([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]));
NSLog(@"frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect([[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame]));
```

and gives me

```
bounds {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
frame {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
```

I using XIBs and "Use Autolayout" is off. **It works fine on iOS 6.**

Have somebody had a similar issue?

http://pixs.ru/showimage/ohpng_7966305_9888841.png

Comment: is the screen filled with your app? or you have black stripes?

Comment: Do you have a `Default-568h.png` in your project]

Comment: @rckoenes `Default-568h.png` is a default name for a launch image. No link with his issue....

Comment: @zbMax, well it has everything to do with the issue. You app will only be 4" if you have a 4" splash screen. If there is not file for the 568 height you app will be displayed in 480 height. So add `Default@2x-568h.png` to your project.

Comment: I have add splash screen 568 height and... no changes) lol Splash screen is small too)

Answer (score 0):

You may be reading these values *before* the actual layout has been done. Try to read them in `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of, say, `-(void)viewDidLoad`.